# Select first element with for loop from dataframe previously concatenated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe concatenated of dataframes:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], keys=[df1,df2,df3], names=['frame'])
```

and want to append the first item of a column from every frame from the big frame to a list.

I tried it with putting all the frames in a list and selecting the first element from every row but get the below error.

> Indexing a MultiIndex with a DataFrame key is not implemented

Edit.: Code I tried

```
keys = [df1, df2, df3]

d = []
for key in keys:
    d.append(df.loc[key]['col1'][0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using this

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], names=['frame'])
df.loc[(df.index.levels[0], 0), 'col1'].tolist()
```

Comment: I have 11 dataframes concatenated but only get 8 values back :/

Comment: Look out for the index in each df, if they did not have default rangeindex then there's a chance they don't have index 0

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keys` parameter of `concat` to add an outermost level to multiindex and groupby it.

```
df = pd.concat(
    [df1,df2,df3], # list of objects to be concatenated
    keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], # list of strings to construct a new outermost level into the multiindex
    names=['frame'] # name for the new level in the multiindex
    # notice if you pass keys=[('df1', 'a'), ('df1', 'b'), ('df3', 'a')]
    # and names=['real frame', 'variation']
    # then the multiindex will have two new levels
)
first_rows = df.groupby('frame').first()
d = first_rows.col1.to_list()
```

On an unrelated note, you should avoid chaining multiple indexings as you did in

```
.loc[key]['col1'][0]
```

And instead do

```
.loc[key, 'col1']
```

...notice your call fails anyway because `keys` being iterated is a list of dataframes that you try to use as index

Comment: Why keys double, one time with and one time without brackets?

Comment: That was my mistake, try it now

Comment: In the concat line, first you pass a list with dataframe objects, then a list of strings to be added to the multiindex as keys, 3rd a string to be used as the name of the new level introduced to the multiindex